# How many API call could be made to Google AdWords and Analytics per day?

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

Is there any API call limit for Google Analytics and Google Adwords and how to get know about these API call limit?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/limits

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because available documentation addresses it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very basic answer would be:

- 50,000 requests per project per day
- 10 queries per second (QPS) per IP.

Detailed info can be found at Google's official devguide:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/limits-quotas?hl=en